# Error with AppCompatAcitivity

Tags: java, android

I have just started working on Android Studio and I am not able to solve this problem. I Have been getting the uploaded errors for a long time. Here are the files I am using. I have checked the package name as well, so that is not the issue.

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    } 

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(
                R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Order"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:onClick="submitOrder" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOcI4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably didn't add the appropriate support lib dependency. Add the following line to the `dependencies` block in your module's `build.gradle` file:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`

> You should also read the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) before using the support libs.

Comment: Thank you, the errors have gone now. But I am unable to launch the app on my phone surprisingly. Whenever I try to launch, my phone's screen goes white for less than a second and then back to the normal home screen.

Comment: What's your minSdkVersion? And which Android runs on your device?